# Configure host upon docker-compose up

Tags: docker, docker-compose, memory-management, redis

**Situation**

So I read that an optimal redis configuration would do this to the host (the specifics are not important, this is just an example see below):

1. Increase max connections
2. Allow to overcommit memory
3. Deactivate transparent huge tables

Normally then on the host system in a shell, I would simply do that:

```
sudo sysctl net.core.somaxconn=1024
sudo sysctl vm.overcommit_memory=1
echo never | sudo tee /sys/kernel/mm/transparent_hugepage/enabled  # includes workaround as sudo echo doen't work
```

Then you would have different commands to make sure that those settings survive a reboot etc.

**Question**

I would like to make sure that when i docker-compose up, all those settings are made on the host machine. I would love to have those settings in the docker compose file, so I don't have to start managing host machines (i don't until now).

**What I've tried so far**

I Tried adding the setting to the docker-compose-file like this:

```
  redis:
    image: redis:latest
    sysctls:
      - net.core.somaxconn=1024
      - sysctl vm.overcommit_memory=1
    command: bash -c "redis-server --appendonly yes"
```

This works for the first setting, but for the second I get the error

```
Error response from daemon: failed to create task for container: failed to create shim task: OCI runtime create failed: runc create failed: sysctl "vm.overcommit_memory" is not in a separate kernel namespace: unknown
```

I've seen solutions to elevate the permissions of the docker container, but for me this defeats the security you have through docker.

Does anyone have a secure and smart solution? Maybe somehow do a separate container which only executes a bash script as sudo? Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1):

As per [docs](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/run/#sysctl) here:

> Not all sysctls are namespaced. Docker does not support changing sysctls inside of a container that also modify the host system. As the kernel evolves we expect to see more sysctls become namespaced.
>
> Currently supported sysctls
>
> IPC Namespace:
>
> - `kernel.msgmax`, `kernel.msgmnb`, `kernel.msgmni`, `kernel.sem`, `kernel.shmall`, `kernel.shmmax`, `kernel.shmmni`, `kernel.shm_rmid_forced`.
> - Sysctls beginning with fs.mqueue.*
>   If you use the --ipc=host option these sysctls are not allowed.
>
> Network Namespace:
>
> - Sysctls beginning with `net.*`
> - If you use the `--network=host` option using these sysctls are not allowed.

A possible solution would only be to create a script, incorporate it in your image or container and run it on start, that's it.

Comment: Thanks, but from my understanding (and your citation of the docs), it is not possible to run this script with any effect from within the container except if you elevate privileges, correct? Would it be a solution to create a separate container with elevated privileges to just do the settings? seems a bit of an overkill to me...

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by elevated privileges. When you run a docker container, all the services running inside are run as `root` unless you specify `USER` somewhere in Dockerfile. And `redis:latest` does not specify a `USER`, see for yourself: https://hub.docker.com/layers/library/redis/latest/images/sha256-21cc29024ab0a6cc3456155f7cc7456a82775e4625368e4f9671c84a0f3951fa?context=explore